# Ethereum network event simulator

Tags: private-blockchain

I would like to simulate and observe an emergent Ethereum network, so I could draw conclusions about the main net and simulate my own code at the infrastructure level. I am looking for the **best tool for the job**, by best meaning well maintained and not having a very steep learning curve.

## TLDR

Are you familiar with a Blockchain simulator that you would recommend?

## My own requirements

1. See the network topology, possibly extrapolate a network graph and run algorithms on top of that graph.
2. Understand how and how fast the structures that contain neighboring peers information fill.

## What I have found

### Bitcoin-Simulator

Not Ethereum related but serves as a good reference for what I would like to find.

Found on this [link](https://arthurgervais.github.io/Bitcoin-Simulator/Installation.html).

The project is not maintained since 2016, uses **ns3** and seems to have a very steep learning curve. Did not have luck in running it either.

### Vibes

Possibly applicable for Ethereum.

Found on this [link](https://github.com/i13-msrg/vibes).

Seems to be made using React and Scala, non of which I am familiar with.

### Geth simulation framework

Found on this [commit](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/commit/9feec51e2dd754819e5c730ac5985d28d57adb48).

Did not test this yet.

## Related questions

[How to simulate p2p network for blockchain systems?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41750/how-to-simulate-p2p-network-for-blockchain-systems).

Comment: So what exactly is your question then?

Comment: I have edited the question for clarity

Comment: Do you mean something like Ganache?

Comment: To my knowledge, Ganache serves as a smart contract testbed, however I have no idea how I would use it to simulate a network topology